MDriven Framework on ARM
is it possible to have a distribution for ARM computers?
On my Mac parallel virtual machine I just can’t install it, I have a message saying that this configuration is not supported
Thanks

We've not had anyone ask for ARM support before. Please send your request to support@mdriven.net and I will bring it up with the team. We're just starting up a new team member that will work extensively with deployment on different platforms. I don't think this will be added until beginning of 2025 at the earliest, but I'm sure we want to support ARM soon.
